# Why "quiet cruise" of a spacecraft would cost NASA 30 mln $ a year?

Tags: nasa, interplanetary, cost

The 2022 Planetary Decadal Survey (Chapter 22) states that "quiet cruise" phase of an interplanetary spacecraft will cost about 30 million dollars a year for NASA. "Quiet cruise" means flight between launch an arrival to destination, with limited communication (about once in a couple of weeks) an no scientific activities.

https://nap.nationalacademies.org/catalog/26522/origins-worlds-and-life-a-decadal-strategy-for-planetary-science

> Examination of recent Discovery and NF cruise costs indicates that a representative quiet cruise phase costs approximately $30 million per year.

I was surprised it costs so much.

**What are the main factors for such high cost?**

Are official documents avalable for public where the costs are detailed?

In my current view,  the costs for small egineering team and communication can't be so high. The engineers don't do so much while there are no techinical problems with the spacecraft. DSN communication is expensive, but is done sparsely in cruise phase.

Currently I can guess. First, reserves are needed for a case of technical problem. Second, on-Earth analogs of the equipment should be stored and maintained for this case. Example is the recent Lucy mission and its solar array deployment problem, that requires larger engineering team to analyse and model the solutions.

**Is 30 mln $ a worst-case estimate, or an average from previous missions?**

Comment: I guessing (so not an answer) that that represents a staff of at most 50 people (more likely 30) and a couple of DSN comm sessions per week. DSN time is **expensive**, as are people who work at JPL.

Comment: I wouldn't be at all surprised if the cost charged to the government for three midlevel engineers at JPL exceeds a million dollars per year. Their salaries and benefits have to be very nice to be competitive in that part of the country. JPL has some very, very nice and very, very cool labs and equipment that are part of the overhead that JPL charges (to the US government) per employee.

Comment: In my first comment, that should be "I'm guessing" rather than "I guessing".

Comment: I was told several years ago when I was in charge of a NASA project as a non-civil servant that I should keep the number of civil servants down to a bare minimum because NASA was trying to go to full cost accounting and the cost of a full-time civil servant was $250000/year. That was several years ago. JPL is not a NASA center in part because that part of the country is **expensive**. The US government cannot compete for high tech employees. JPL can. I wouldn't be surprised if the full-cost accounting charge for a JPL engineer is half a million per year.

Comment: @David Hammen - but are all those tens of speialists on full-time duty for only this space mission? I have much less inside than you. But from what I've read, I imagine for cruise phase and non-emergency mode most of the specialists will be on part-duty at most. They will be occupied by other work, and their salaries will be contributed by this work. Am I wrong here?

Comment: @Heopps they are likely doing other things than babysitting the spacecraft, but other things for the mission so it still "bills back" to the mission cost

Comment: 30m a year seems relatively cheap for anything in space made by nasa, even if it’s not doing too much at the time

Comment: Does it also include the consumables onboard?

Comment: @user253751 There's no knowing how they did their accounting, but consumables used during coast certainly needs taken into account.